# 'Security error" code: "1000' in Audio API example

Tags: firefox, html, audio

I'm trying to repeat the example from [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API#Complete_Example%3a_Visualizing_Audio_Spectrum), but am getting this error:

```
Security error" code: "1000
 var fb = event.frameBuffer,
```

Everything in my folder have 777 rights, but it's still is giving me it. My Firefox version is 4.0, so Audio API features should be available. What could be the problem? I've copied the example without any change. Any suggestion would help, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make sure your audio and web page are same origin, and if you're doing this from a file:/// URI, you have to tell Firefox to not force origin checks, see our note here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API#Security

Comment: Thanks, that helped. If someone would have the same issue, just go to your `about:config` in firefox and disable the `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy`.