# frameBuffer, html5 canvas Audio API, insecure operation error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-audio

I am just playing around with html5 canvas and I want to make a spectrum for sound playing. I've followed a couple of tutorials, but it keeps telling me that the operation is insecure. I've copypasted direct code from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introducing_the_Audio_API_Extension and I know frameBuffer works because I've also tried the codesnippets from here: http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/blizzard/audio-slideshow/#slide2

It seemst to work perfect on this site, but when I copy the code to mine, it just does not work.

Here's a jsfiddle (must be opened in FF 14 >):
http://jsfiddle.net/6GMVC/2/

The error I get is:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
var frameBuffer = event.frameBuffer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a cross-domain error -- there is a discussion of a similar issue here:

['Security error" code: "1000' in Audio API example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677985/security-error-code-1000-in-audio-api-example)

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers deny the use of cross-domain includes for many html5 elements. Try to use audio files that are on the same server / domain / localhost

If you are not running a server for you project, (which is possible with just an .html file) try open it from your localhost server instead of (for example) a folder on your desktop

here you can find a free to use apache server http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html